# Conditional background color for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, colors

I'm trying to set the background color for a subclassed `UITableViewCell`.  I know that normally I'm supposed to use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.  However, I have some logic to customize several aspects of the `UITableViewCell` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and I would like to set the background color of the cell based on that logic.  Do I have to duplicate the whole set of conditions I have in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` just to set the background color?  That kind of code repetition seems wasteful and probably unwise.

The best solution I can think of is to add a UIColor property to the `UITableViewCell` subclass, set it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` based on the conditions there, and just have `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` set the cell's background color to its own color property.  Is this the right way to handle this situation?  It seems kinda clunky, but I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 1):

You can create function returning appropriate color and set it accordingly like

```
-(UIColor*)getColorForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*){
    UIColor *cellColor=nil;
    //Do whatever your logic is for finding appropriate color assign to cellColor
    return cellColor;
}
```

Now use this function to setcolor as, so you have to modify only 1 place to effect at both place.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    .... //Your code for cell

    cell.backgroundColor = [self getColorForIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    .... //Your code for cell

    cell.backgroundColor = [self getColorForIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Note : This will still work if you place only at any of the delegate method, so no need to call at 2 places.

Comment: That just moves where the duplicate code would be.  I have conditional logic in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that customizes several other aspects of the cell, and I'm trying to avoid copying those conditions into another method just to set background color

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out if there's a good way to avoid code duplication here.  This solution results in code duplication because the conditional logic that decides how to customize the cell (including the background color) would need to be present in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for things like label text and button function, and again in the `getColorForIndexPath:` function you proposed to select the appropriate background color.